# Angular Router - how do you create a dynamic route without a forward slash

Tags: javascript, angular

Here is my routes array. I want any route with the- to use the first component, and any other to use the second component.

```
[
    { 
        path: 'the-:param',
        component: MyComponent
    },
    { 
        path: ':param',
        component: MyOtherComponent
    }
]
```

Any ideas how to achieve this. Using angular 7.

Comment: Write a custom router module so you can implement your rules instead of Angular's.

Comment: Thanks - no way to do it with the current angular router? Sound like a lot of work. Looking for a solution that's more maintainable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A custom URL matcher can be provided when a combination of path and pathMatch isn't expressive enough.

```
function leadingtThe(url: UrlSegment[]) {
  return url.length === 1 && url[0].path.startsWith('the-') ? ({consumed: url}) : null;
}

const routes: Routes = [{ matcher: leadingtThe, component: MyComponent }];
```

this should match any leading `the-` in the incoming path.

the `url.length === 1` this here to make sure that the url only one segment, if its more than one then the function return null and will not match.

if you want to match any url that starts with `the-` even if its more than one segment like for example `localhost:4200/the-anything/segment/someothersegment`
then it should be:

```
function leadingtThe(url: UrlSegment[]) {
  return url[0].path.startsWith('the-') ? ({consumed: url}) : null;
}

const routes: Routes = [{ matcher: leadingtThe, component: MyComponent }];
```

Comment: UrlSegment - exactly what I was looking for - thanks for the example Mahmoud!